# SQL Express 2014 silent installation not working with C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, silent-installer

I have tried the silent installation of SQL Express 2014 with C# pro-grammatically.
Here is the code i tried.

```
string strSQLPath = "C:\\SQLEXPR.exe";

string SQLfn = strSQLPath;

string SQLp = @"/QS SAPWD=""C0mp!ex"" ConfigurationFile=""C:\Configuration.ini""";


ProcessStartInfo psiSQL = new ProcessStartInfo(SQLfn, SQLp);
Process SQLprocess = new Process();
try
{
    SQLprocess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psiSQL);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
try
{
    SQLprocess.WaitForExit();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

I followed the configuration.ini file preparation from below link.

[SQL Server Express Silent Installation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/835c123e-7c3e-4eef-bc47-e2ee700187c1/sql-server-express-silent-installation?forum=sqlexpress)

I also tried the following argument series.

```
//string SQLp = "/qn INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS ADDLOCAL=ALL";
//string SQLp = @"/qs Action=Install InstanceName=SQLExpress";

//string SQLp = @"/qs Action=Install IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms=True Features=SQL,Tools InstanceName=SQLExpress SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=""Builtin\Administrators"" SQLSVCACCOUNT=""DomainName\UserName"" SQLSVCPASSWORD=""StrongPassword""";

//string SQLp = "/qs Action=Install Hideconsole Features=SQL,Tools InstanceName=SQLEXPRESS SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=Administrators SQLSVCACCOUNT=global\admin SQLSVCPASSWORD=password";
//string SQLp = "/q ACTION=INSTALL INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS ADDLOCAL=ALL ROLE=AllFeatures_WithDefaults ENU=True QUIET=True INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server";
```

None of the command is working for me. SQL Express Edition is not getting installed at all.

It does now show any error (may be because of QS command), but finally i dont see any SQL component got installed (referring control panel)

Please suggest to resolve the issue.

Note: I am using "Express 64BIT\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe" which has been downloaded from the Microsoft download page.

Comment: Are you able to perform a silent installation with this command line? If you can't write a batch file that works, doing the same in C# won't help.

Answer (score 1):

The following command works for me...

> Setup.exe /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS
>   /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD="Password1" /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT
>   AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS"
>   /IACCEPTSQ LSERVERLICENSETERMS /SkipInstallerRunCheck /QS

Answer (score 0):

```
    var newPro = Process.Start(sq\SetupfilePath, @"/q /Action=Install /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /Hideconsole /Features=SQLEngine /InstanceName=SQLEXPRESS  /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=""NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"" /SQLSVCACCOUNT=""NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"" /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=""Automatic""");
```